# Post ajax request fails on IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post

i have a simple form that sends an ajax post request

```
.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        data: {
            "m": magazine,
            "l": email,
            "p": password,
        },
        type:"POST",
        contentType: 'text/plain',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        callback: "onSmData",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
};
```

it works on firefox and chrome, however it fails and goes to the error message on IE9.
Ive tried  this https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest and it did not work, i tried adding the cache:false too cause apparently thats an issue with IE.

does anyone know any work around for IE? or it is just not supported?

Comment: What URL are you posting to?  Is it on the same domain?  Why do you have `contentType: 'text/plain'`?  Also, `callback` isn't a valid parameter to `$.ajax` (did you mean `jsonpCallback`)?  Remember, JSON and JSONP are 2 very different things.

Comment: callback should be without quote... `callback: onSmData`

Comment: @C-linkNepal: Actually, `callback` isn't even a valid parameter.

Comment: contentType: 'text/plain' should be contentType: 'text/html' ??

Comment: its cross Domain I added the contentType because on another answer it said it could help too.

Comment: @C-linkNepal: That's the `Content-type` of the *request*.  It should usually be omitted unless the server expects a certain thing.

Comment: @AdrianMojica: Are you trying to make a CORS request?

Comment: It's possible the server isn't set up to receive data as `text/plain`.

Comment: "it fails and goes to the error message on IE9"... What error?  Can you show the *exact* error?

Comment: took the text plain off, makes no difference. IE9 throws no error at all.

Comment: @AdrianMojica: Then what did you mean by "it fails and goes to the error message on IE9"?

Comment: i have this onError 

var onError = function(xOptions, textStatus) {
   var fail ="error";
   showStatus("Could not authenticate due to error.");
  };

Comment: @AdrianMojica: Why not try to print the *actual* message sent to the `error` callback?  `var onError = function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status);  console.log(error);  };`.